# Помогите решить ошибку в коде Unity2d!

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять в чем причина ошибки. Только и пишет одно и тоже сообщение:

> Assets\Scripts\Inventory\Slot.cs(27,41): error CS1061: 'Spawn' does not contain a definition for 'SpawnDroppedItem' and no accessible extension method 'SpawnDroppedItem' accepting a first argument of type 'Spawn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Помогите пожалуйста!
Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Inventory inventory;
    public int i;

    private void Start()
    {
        inventory = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Inventory>();
    }
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (transform.childCount <= 0)
        {
            inventory.isFull[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public void DropItem()
    {
        foreach(Transform child in transform)
        {
            child.GetComponent<Spawn>().SpawnDroppedItem();
            GameObject.Destroy(child.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru&sl=en&tl=ru&text=%27Spawn%27%20does%20not%20contain%20a%20definition%20for%20%27SpawnDroppedItem%27%20and%20no%20accessible%20extension%20method%20%27SpawnDroppedItem%27%20accepting%20a%20first%20argument%20of%20type%20%27Spawn%27%20could%20be%20found%20(are%20you%20missing%20a%20using%20directive%20or%20an%20assembly%20reference%3F).&op=translate)

Comment: Код из интернета не работает?

Comment: @aepot *trollface*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в строке `child.GetComponent<Spawn>().SpawnDroppedItem();` Вы пытаетесь получить объект `Spawn`, но Вы уверены, что такой объект существует?
Возможно, у вас отсутствует директива `using` или ссылка на сборку

Comment: Спасибо огромное!